# Javascript alert based on prompt value

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, alert, prompt

I am trying to make a script in which a prompt window will pop up asking a question, and based on what the answer in it is, an alert box will pop up saying that the answer is valid or invalid. In my code, my prompt box works, but my alert box didn't. Can someone help me solve this problem please? Thank you so so much!!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var City=prompt("Enter your city", "City");
function checkName(){
    var validLetters=/^[a-z]+$/i;
    if(validLetters.test(City))
        alert("Your input is accepted!");
    else
        alert("Your input is invalid!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `checkName`? You define it but never call it (ie you need `checkName()` to run it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the function `checkName` with argument `City` or you could use `global-variable`.

You are not calling the function in your script to test the value of `prompt`

```js
var City = prompt("Enter your city", "City");
checkName(City);

function checkName(City) {
  var validLetters = /^[a-z]+$/i;
  if (validLetters.test(City))
    alert("Your input is accepted!");
  else
    alert("Your input is invalid!");
}
```

Comment: @linda, Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Comment: wait! Can you help me with one more question please?

Comment: @linda, You can post many question as you like.. There are many developers to help if it a valid question as per the SO criteria..

Comment: @linda, As said earlier, you can post new question with expected output and your efforts...

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your fucntion checkName . call this function after prompt .

```
var City = prompt("Enter your city", "City");

checkName(City);  // function to be called 

function checkName(City) {
  var validLetters = /^[a-z]+$/i;
  if (validLetters.test(City))
    alert("Your input is accepted!");
  else
    alert("Your input is invalid!");
}
```